# Properly align columns in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I tried to create a column chart in highcharts to display monthly data on a datetime axis. The problem is that the spacing between the bars is different. For example after the month february there is only a small spacing whereas after other months the spacing is bigger. Maybe this is happening because the month feburary only has 28 days.
Anyway here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: [{
      type: 'datetime'
    }, {
      type: 'datetime',
      visible: false
    }],

    plotOptions: {
      column: {
                grouping: false,
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0,
        pointPlacement: 'between'
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Year',
      xAxis: 1,
      data: [25],
      zIndex: 4,
      color: '#222',
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1),
      pointInterval: 1,
      pointIntervalUnit: 'year'
    }, {
      name: 'Month',
      data: [50, 100, 130, 160, 170, 200, 170, 165, 250, 200, 230, 160],
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1),
      pointInterval: 1,
      pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
      zIndex: 2,
      color: 'red',
    }],
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bosngxk1/2/

I also added another bar for the whole year. You notice the already mentioned problem with the spacing and that the year area is a bit too wide. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Yes your assumption is right. the spacing variation is because not all months have same number of days. If you want to show month wise data and the columns are limited then you can go for categorical x axis. that will give equal spacing between the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind, you can use Highstock. There is an axis option called `ordinal`. With that set to true (by default), all points are equally spaced. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k0k2n83p/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess there is no other option than using categorical x axis. I don't like this solution since I somehow have to hardcode datetime values instead of using datetime formatters and so on.
Anyway by defining the xAxis as follows I get the desired chart layout.

```
xAxis: [{
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
    },
    {
        categories: [
            '2017'
        ],
        visible: false
    }]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hho4zrso/